# require("sdk/selection").text for now its not working in e10s. What to replace it with?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, e10s

`require("sdk/selection").text` for now its not working in e10s.

I try `activeTab.attach` and `port`s and `window.getSelected.toString()` but this is very slowly.

What to replace it with?

Comment: They'll fix it before e10s hits release, so don't worry just keep using it. But if you need it usuable just temporarily probably go with non e10s solution of CPOW: `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null).gBrowser.contetnWindow.getSe`